# How to configure email headers with node js

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer

```
function sendmail(req,res){
 const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',   
  auth: {           
   user: 'myemail@gmail.com',
   pass: 'mypassword'
  }
 });  
 const mailOptions = {
  from: 'Something',
  to: 'to_email',
  subject: 'My subject',
  html: `<button>My Button</button>`
 };    
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)
}
```

When I send the email everything arrives without problems, however, for the email `from` it doesn't work, when the email I received arrives, the email from which should be `Something` is the email of the sender the email, so basically if I send an email to `123@outlook.com` from my email `123@gmail` and set the `from` to `something` when I send and the email is received , the email from is not something, but `123@gmail` which is the email responsible for sending it.  How can I fix this to display Something instead of the email responsible for sending

Comment: Sure: emails get routed by email servers, who will look at your headers and go "yeah this is not a real from field, so I am not sending this on unaltered". Use the proper format for a `from` sender [as per the official nodemailer documentation](https://nodemailer.com/message/)

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans I can do this with python

Comment: Why would that be relevant to how you're using Nodemailer? Their instructions are your baseline - if those don't work, that's weird and worth digging into, but right now you're not using what they say you should be using =)

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans I'm doing tests, in the future I want to use it for marketing purposes, and I can't find an answer to this, I've already looked at Google and it seems that they work for them, I don't understand what happens, and I've been researching this for days

Comment: The docs are right there, I even linked to them for you, and they link out further to the exact address specification if things are still unclear. So first change your code to actually use what nodemailer tells you to use. If that doesn't work, cool: update your post to show the actual test values you're using.

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans Friend, I made a point of reading the documentation again, but I still couldn't, how can I do this in practice

Comment: So [update your post](/help/how-to-ask), because comments are not post details, and just saying you tried doesn't tell anyone _what_ you tried. Show what you tried in your post, so that everyone knows what you really tried, so they don't need to ask/suggest that.